# Некорректно отображаются товары

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Всем доброго времени суток.
Использую тему [betheme](https://themeforest.net/item/betheme-responsive-multipurpose-wordpress-theme/7758048)
И почему-то слетело корректное отображение товаров
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как видно первый товар добавляется корректно,последующие добавляются НЕ в список ul.
Как я полагаю,нужно смотреть в файле archive-product.php?
Заранее благодарю за ответы.
UPD:
Вот файл [archive-product.php](https://pastebin.com/ixLE5EEp)

Comment: Если вы этот файл не трогали, то и смотреть в него нечего. Странно, что он такой древней версии 2.0.0. Какие версии темы и WooCommerce на сайте?

Comment: @KAGGDesign благодарю за ответ,версия вукомерса 3.
Ошибка была в content-product.php,забыл закрыть <div>,поэтому верстка полетела)